# Display an image on a Leaflet map using geojson attributes

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geojson, features, typeerror

I have a geojson file "test.geojson" which contains image metadata for multiple images, including image url (as `browseUrl`) and image bounds (as `imageBounds`).

What I want to do is to display a **corresponding image** on my leaflet map by **clicking on it's shape** using [ImageOverlay](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#imageoverlay). Here is my code:

```
$.getJSON("test.geojson", function (geojson) {
    var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON(geojson, {
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            layer.on('click', function (feature) {
                L.imageOverlay(feature.properties.browseurl, feature.properties.imageBounds).addTo(map)
            })
        }
    }).addTo(map);
});
```

Unfortunatelly I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'browseurl' of undefined` when I click on a feature.

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: @whyzar Leaflet 1.2.0

Answer (score 1):

This appears to have been a bug at some point, unsure if resolved [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined #555](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/issues/555)

A user does recommend using this as a possible workaround:

> Can work around this by adding an empty function before creating the draw control:
>   `L.EditToolbar.Edit.prototype._editStyle = function() {};`

Comment: Could you specify where exactly should I put this code?

Comment: Try adding the empty function before creating the draw control